# Whey Protein before or after workout? type 1 diabetic.

Tags: workout, protein

as it says in the post I am type 1 diabetic, I got it randomly when I turned 23, I am in pretty good shape, work construction everyday, I'm 6ft 165. I am trying to put on some weight and whey protein has basically no carbs, just calories and protein which is perfect because it wont make my sugar spike up. I do the gym a few days a week after work, or on the weekends, but not working out everyday other than manual labor in construction. When should I take the protein? In the morning before work? or before the gym if I'm not working that day? Or should I take it after work or after a workout? any opinions would help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Muscle Development

---

It’s a common belief that a rush of fast-acting carbohydrates along with whey protein is ideal.  In reality is you don’t have to "spike" your insulin; a slow, insulin response *(as seen with low glycemic carbohydrates)* will provide much the same muscle protein synthesis benefits as a rapid, acute surge.

---

**Insulin's Role**

Insulin is a highly anabolic hormone that is conducive to skeletal muscle protein synthesis requires an external source of amino acids to create this effect.

A state of hyperinsulinemia *(high insulin levels)* and hyperaminoacidemia *(high levels of amino acids)* will facilitates muscle protein synthesis, and what better way to induce such a state then by simply eating protein and carbohydrates together.

This does not mean "the more insulin the better" some insulin does increase muscle protein synthesis response. There is a point where extra insulin doesn’t facilitate a more intense response.

---

> **Bottom line** 
>   It's critical that you're eating protein and carbs together.  Post workout is when your body requires protein to aid recovery and facilitate increases in muscle mass.

---

*Sources:*

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27271661
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9022953
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28296942

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you should have protein in the morning or afternoon when your day is still going. Protein is a little difficult to digest so taking it in morning is a better choice. It shouldn't matter if you take it after or before workout as the purpose is to repair the torn muscles. Given that you do construction  work everyday, I think it is good if you take it in morning time when you start your day. Also, on the days when you are not working, just to give your body time to digest the protein you should go for morning.